# Problems with Jquery .get() jqXHR shows a valid return, but calls .fail()

Tags: json, jquery

The Code:

```
function readfile(company)
{
    var url = "JSON/" + company + ".json"

    $.get(url,function(data){
                parse(data)
        })
        .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            console.log("FAILURE!");
            console.log(errorThrown)
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(jqXHR);
        });
}
```

The Response:

```
FAILURE! reader.js:10
SyntaxError {} reader.js:11
parsererror reader.js:12
Object {...}
```

The thing that's killing me is that the network tab shows the JSON is loaded, the response status in jqXHR is 200 and "OK", etc... but jQuery keeps running .fail()

Checked the json [here](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/), and it shows it as valid, so does netbeans/eclipse (trying to cover all my bases here), and still jquery says no.

Network tools shows `application/json` as mime type, and

```
Request Method:GET
Status Code:304 Not Modified
```

although jqXHR shows

```
status: 200
```

Clearly I'm doing something wrong. Any ideas?

Note: not a cross origin request, on localhost running WAMP, server is online. Monitor is plugged in.

Comment: Have you tried using $.getJSON ?

Comment: is your MIME type really in upper case like that?

Comment: Can we see what the returned JSON looks like?  `console.log(jqXHR.responseText)`

Comment: @Alnitak, nope. I'm just frustrated and held down the shift key by accident. shows up in all lower case.

Comment: @RocketHazmat, it comes back as a (very long) string "{companyname:{...}}" (the ... is not really there, but the company info is confidential. can't post their details on SO. suffice to say, matches the contents of the JSON file in eclipse/netbeans. although it shows newline characters in the chrome console.

Comment: if it really says `companyname:` without quotes around the key it's not strictly legal JSON.

Comment: Try using http://json.parser.online.fr/ to validate your JSON.  The [site you tried](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/) accepts invalid JSON like `{test: 'a'}` (it should be `{"test": "a"}`).

Comment: and we have a winner. @Alnitak, you are correct, sir. despite the fact that both IDE's and the stupid JSON viewer said, "Hey, this is totes valid JSON", I needed to put the keys in quotes for jQuery. I swear sometimes she's such a primadona. Also my IDE's are idiots and I should know not to trust them.

Comment: @JasonNichols: It's a valid JavaScript object, but not valid JSON.  That's probably why your IDE isn't yelling at you; it probably thinks it's a JavaScript file.  The JSON viewer you're using probably just uses `eval`, so since it's a valid JS object, it worked.  Here's a *better* JSON viewer: http://json.parser.online.fr/ or http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @JasonNichols it's not jQuery's fault - it's also required by Chrome's native `JSON.parse` method, which jQuery will use if present.

Comment: Still irritated that the computer always does what I say instead of what I mean. I've been writing code with it long enough, it should know not to trust me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the snippet posted in the comments, the error appears to be that legal [JSON](http://www.json.org/) requires that the keys (and any string values) be enclosed in double-quotes.